# How can i replace text "Add to cart" with an icon (Add to cart button woocommerce)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook

I've tried to replace button text with an icon, but following code return the text not the icon.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'woo_custom_product_add_to_cart_text' );  // 2.1 +

function woo_custom_product_add_to_cart_text() {  
    return __( '<i class="fa fa-cart-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>', 'woocommerce' );

}
```

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/304517/woocommerce-changing-add-to-cart-button-text-as-icon/304523 this link will help you as it cleary tells that it uses esc_html function which escapes HTML blocks in return value.

Answer (score 0):

try this >>

```
function remove_button_loop(){
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
}
add_action('init','remove_button_loop');
function add_to_cart_replace() {
    global $product;
    $link = $product->get_permalink();
    echo do_shortcode('<a href="'.$link.'" class="button addtocartbutton"><i class="fa fa-shopping-bag"></i></a>');
}
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item','add_to_cart_replace');
```